# Show that $a^2\le ab \lt b^2$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Another homework proof verification.  This time it is this;

> If $0\le a \lt b,$ show that $a^2 \le ab \lt b^2.$  Show by example that it does NOT follow that $a^2 \lt ab \lt b^2$.

So here's what I have.
$$0 \le a \lt b  \text{ (Given) }$$
$$0 \le ab \lt b^2$$
Also
$$0 \le a \lt b  \text{ (Given) }$$
$$0 \le a^2 \lt ab$$
So from here i can say
$$0 \le a^2 \lt ab \lt b^2$$
Since $a\ge0$, if in fact $a=0$
$$0 \le 0^2 \le 0b \lt b^2$$
So i can say then that $a^2 \le ab \lt b^2$.
Is this sound?  Is there a smoother way?

Comment: A smoother way could be this: $b=a+x$ for some $x>0$, then, $a^2 <= a(a+x) = a^2 + ax < (a+x)^2 = a^2 + 2ax + x^2$.

Comment: The argument is not clear. For the second part, it is enough to say let $a=0$, $b=1$. Then it is not true that $a^2\lt ab$.

Comment: $a$ should be equal to $0$ in the counterexample.

Comment: So then $(a+x)^2=b^2$ which means that $a^2+2ax+x^2=b^2$, but how to incorporate $ab$?

Comment: I forgot to include that counterexample...

Comment: $ab = a(a+x) = a^2 + ax$ Hope that helps.

Comment: As to the inequalities, it depends on what has been proved already. Fpr example, we are given that $a\lt b$, so that $b-a\gt 0$. Then $b^2-ab=b(b-a)$. If you already know that the product of two positives is positive, you can conclude that $b^2-ab\gt 0$, that is, $ab\lt b^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem asked for an example, which is a specific set of values for $a,b$.

Take $a=0, b=1$.  Then the hypothesis $0\le a<b$ is satisfied, as is the conclusion $a^2\le ab<b^2$, but not $a^2<ab<b^2$, because $a^2=0\not<0=ab$.